# Change background color of BottomBar

Tags: android

I'm using this great library you can see [here](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) but cant seem to set the bg color for the bottomBar.

The code I'm using to set up the bottomBar is this :

```
    bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(view, savedInstanceState);
    bottomBar.setMaxFixedTabs(2);
    bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_bottom_bar, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onMenuTabSelected: " + menuItemId );
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onMenuTab- RE - Selected: " + menuItemId );
        }
    });

    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, R.color.colorAccentPink);
    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, R.color.colorAccentPink);
    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, R.color.colorAccentPink);
```

I have also tried to set the setBackground method but didnt have any luck.

All i' getting is white background.

Thank you

EDIT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/bb_menu_comments"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_comments"
    android:title="Comments" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/bb_menu_poll"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_poll"
    android:title="Polls" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/bb_menu_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:title="Share" />
```

Comment: Post your xml code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a wrong parameter to the `mapColorForTab` method. `R.color.colorAccentPink` is just a resource id, but you need to extract color from it like this:

```
bottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccentPink));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mBottomBar.getBar().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
```

Try this line. It works perfect for me.